# Ionic 3 (cordova) app from http url does not open as app but it opens in the browser

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 3 and i want to load my app from cloud. For this I am made changes to the path of index.html.The app opens fine in android but in IOS app opens in the browser. I want to open this as app. Here are the changes to my index.html in the config.xml

```
<content src="https://example.com/index.html" />
```

Comment: use '_self' flag to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to allow the navigation to that url. Add this to the config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="https://example.com/*" />
```